# Android Wear: Asset in dataMap but can't be retrieved?

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm storing a thumbnail picture with my data as an asset.  On the Wear side, it doesn't show up sometimes.  However, if I debug, I can clearly see that the DataMapItem does contain a HashMapEntry with key "photo" and data behind it "Asset[@<RANDOM_CHARACTERS>]"

However, calling dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("photo") returns null.

[image: Picture of the debug session]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asset has the key "photo " - note the space at the end, yet you try to retrieve it using "photo". The keys need to match exactly.

Comment: Correct. I must have accidentally hit space when I thought I was in another program.  Shame on my for not using constants.  Thanks!